# Render child content in parent template

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a stepper in Angular 5 as an exercise, but am completely stumped on how to go about this.  Basically, I want to be able to create a stepper of X steps, and render the content of each step.  Right now each step is rendering as [Object object] instead of the text between the elements.  How do I render the step's contents in the parent template?

Here are my components:

```
import { Component, ContentChildren, Input, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ 
  selector: 'step',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class Step {
  constructor () { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'stepper',
  template: `
    <ul class="stepper stepper-horizontal">
      <li *ngFor="let step of steps; index as i"
        [ngClass]="{
          active: idx === (i + 1),
          completed: idx > (i + 1)
        }">
        <a>
          <span class="circle">
            {{i + 1}}
          </span>
          <span class="label">
            {{ step }}
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class Stepper {
  @ContentChildren(Step)
  readonly steps: QueryList<Step>;

  private idx: number = 1;

  constructor () { }

  next () {
    if (this.idx < this.steps.length) this.idx++;
  }

  prev () {
    if (this.idx > 1) this.idx--;
  }
}
```

And this is an example of the template I want to write:

```
<stepper>
  <step>Step 1</step>
  <step>Step 2</step>
  <step>Step 3</step>
</stepper>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a more elegant answer, but this worked:

```
@Directive({ selector: 'step' })
export class Step {
  constructor (private element: ElementRef) { }

  get text () { return this.element.nativeElement.innerText; }
}
```

And then just rendered {{ step.text }} in the stepper.  If there's a better way I'd love to know!